# Comparing a List<T> with another List<t>

Tags: c#, list, compare, equals, iequatable

I have been reading on how to compare a list with one annother. I have tried to implement the `IEquatable` interface.  Here is what i have done so far:

```
/// <summary>
/// A object holder that contains a service and its current failcount
/// </summary>
public class ServiceHolder : IEquatable<ServiceHolder>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="service"></param>
    public ServiceHolder(Service service)
    {
        Service = service;
        CurrentFailCount = 0;
    }
    public Service Service { get; set; }
    public UInt16 CurrentFailCount { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Public equal method
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        ServiceHolder tmp = obj as ServiceHolder;
        if (tmp == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return Equals(tmp);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks the internal components compared to one annother
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceHolder"></param>
    /// <returns>tru eif they are the same else false</returns>
    public bool Equals(ServiceHolder serviceHolder)
    {
        if (serviceHolder == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (this.Service.Id == serviceHolder.Service.Id)
        {
            if (this.Service.IpAddress == serviceHolder.Service.IpAddress)
            {
                if (this.Service.Port == serviceHolder.Service.Port)
                {
                    if (this.Service.PollInterval == serviceHolder.Service.PollInterval)
                    {
                        if (this.Service.ServiceType == serviceHolder.Service.ServiceType)
                        {
                            if (this.Service.Location == serviceHolder.Service.Location)
                            {
                                if (this.Service.Name == this.Service.Name)
                                {
                                    return true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and this is where I use it:

```
 private void CheckIfServicesHaveChangedEvent()
 {
     IList<ServiceHolder> tmp;
     using (var db = new EFServiceRepository())
     {
         tmp = GetServiceHolders(db.GetAll());
     }

     if (tmp.Equals(Services))
     {
         StateChanged = true;
     }
     else
     {
         StateChanged = false;
     }
 }
```

Now when I debug and I put a break point in the equals function it never gets hit.

This leads me to think I have implemented it incorrectly or Im not calling it correctly?

Comment: `tmp` is a list not a single `ServiceHolder`.

Comment: Cant I compare two lists?

Comment: As a general style guideline, avoid using variable names like `tmp`. If your variable is of type `ServiceHolder`, you can call it `serviceHolder`. If it's a collection of objects of type `ServiceHolder`, you can call it `serviceHolders`. At first when I saw several `tmp` I assumed that they shared the same type. Type confusion should not be encouraged.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to compare the contents of two lists then the best method is `SequenceEqual`.

```
if (tmp.SequenceEquals(Services))
```

This will compare the contents of both lists using equality semantics on the values in the list.  In this case the element type is `ServiceHolder` and as you've already defined equality semantics for this type it should work just fine

**EDIT**

OP commented that order of the collections shouldn't matter.  For that scenario you can do the following

```
if (!tmp.Except(Services).Any())
```

Comment: Will this check the order of the lists? As I donot care about the order?

Comment: @Zapnologica this will require the order to be the same, if you don't care about order then you'll need to use a method like `Except`

Comment: Or you should store your objects in a collection that doesn't order elements such as a `HashSet` (C# >= 3.5), if you don't need order.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare lists without the order most easily with linq.

```
 List<ServiceHolder> result = tmp.Except(Services).ToList();
```